# Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position with RecyclerView on Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm calling API to get data from server for both sides and adding data into `RecyclerView` but whenever I scroll fast I get an error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:10
```

It was working fine few days back so I feel that this is the issue of `RecyclerView`. This issue only come whenever I scroll upwards after scrolling downwards.

I'm using scroll listener of `RecyclerView` as

```
 //Scroll Listener
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold) && customersList.size() > 0) {
                // End has been reached
                // Do something
                loading = true;
                //calling API
                if (!NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(getActivity()).equals(getString(R.string.not_connected_to_internet))) {
                    getCustomersList(customersList.get(totalItemCount - 1).getCreatedTs(), "2"
                            , customerDetailSearchEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                } else {
                    if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And I call API and update adapter of the `RecyclerView` as

```
try {
                if (apiResponse.getSuccess()) {
                    for (Customers customers : apiResponse.getData().getCustomers()) {
                        if (apiResponse.getData().getCustomers() != null) {
                            if (traversalValue.equals("2")) {
                                customersList.add(customers);
                                dataChanged = "yes";
                            } else if (traversalValue.equals("1")) {
                                if (swipeRefreshLayout != null && swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                                    // To remove duplicate items
                                    if (!time.equals(customers.getCreatedTs())) {
                                        customersList.add(0, customers);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    customersList.add(customers);
                                }
                                dataChanged = "yes";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    loading = false;
                }
                if (customersList != null && customersList.size() == 0) {
                    textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (sortValue != 0) {
                    bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (sortValue == 1 || sortValue == 2) {
                        //Sorted
                        sortSpannable = new SpannableString("Sorted by : ");
                        sortSpannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 0, 9, 0); // set size
                        sortTextView.setText(sortSpannable);

                        if (sortValue == 1) {
                            sortedBySpannable = new SpannableString("Amount(Asc)");
                        } else {
                            sortedBySpannable = new SpannableString("Amount(Desc)");
                        }
                        sortTextView.append(sortedBySpannable);
                    } else if (sortValue == 3 || sortValue == 4) {
                        //Sorted
                        sortSpannable = new SpannableString("Sorted by : ");
                        sortSpannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 0, 9, 0); // set size
                        sortTextView.setText(sortSpannable);

                        if (sortValue == 3) {
                            sortedBySpannable = new SpannableString("Name(A-Z)");
                        } else {
                            sortedBySpannable = new SpannableString("Name(Z-A)");
                        }
                        sortTextView.append(sortedBySpannable);
                    }
                } else {
                    bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (swipeRefreshLayout != null && swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                if (traversalValue.equals("2")) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            customerMainFragmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    if (dataChanged != null && dataChanged.equals("yes")) {
                        // recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(customerMainFragmentAdapter.getItemCount() + 1);
                    }
                } else if (traversalValue.equals("1")) {
                    if (dataChanged != null && dataChanged.equals("yes")) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                customerMainFragmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (swipeRefreshLayout != null && swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
```

The complete stacktrace is as:

```
 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 9(offset:9).state:10                                                                            atandroid.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5512)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I've already searched it and tried many solutions din't work. The difference in my source code is

1. It adds data in same `ArrayList` on pull to refresh.
2. It adds data into end of `RecyclerView` whenever we scroll down. So we cannot clear `ArrayList` here.

Hope I have explained my problem properly and you guys would help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you call `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` in your adapter, `onScrolled` method of the listener gets called again because you set loading to false too early and your recycleView is not updated yet.

I suggest you set `loading = false` after your smooth scrolling to the position is done. Or you can just call `recyclerLog.scrollTo(0)` and skip the whole smooth thing.

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm still getting same problem.

Comment: You mean you commented out `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` and the problem still occurs? The exception clearly says `Invalid item position 0`. It means your dataList is empty at the time.

Comment: Yes, but I got `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 9(offset:9).state:10` now while scrolling back from top to bottom.